# Progressbar dose not show every time WebView goes to a link

Tags: android, webview, android-progressbar

i have a webview in my android application and a progress bar to show activity. But ProgressBar only show first time when app loads a url after that if i tap on a link within webview progressbar doesnt show up! here is my code.

inside OnCreateView

```
dialog = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        dialog.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

and

```
private class MyWebClient extends WebViewClient {
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                dialog.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
          }    
}
```

Comment: Where is your onPageStarted() method, in that method make it visible

Comment: sorry i am new to android development can you please tell me where should i put that method?

Comment: Inside MyWebClient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void startWebView(String url) {

    if (Utils.isConnectedToInternet(this)) {

        progressDialog = null;

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

                if (progressDialog == null) {
                    progressDialog = progressDialog.show(PurchaseActivity.this, "", "Loading...", true, false);
                }
            }

            //If you will not use this method url links are opeen in new brower not in webview
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                try {
                    if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        progressDialog = null;
                    }
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });

        // Javascript inabled on webview
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // Other webview options
    /*
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    */

    /*
     String summary = "<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points.</body></html>";
     webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);
     */

        //Load url in webview
        webView.loadUrl(url);


    } else {

        messages.showErrorInConnection(this);

    }
}
```